# Mustache_Autoloader missing with Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, mustache, autoload, autoloader

I dowload the last versión of Mustache (2.7) with Composer,

```
"require": {
        "mustache/mustache" : "2.7.*",
        // etc...
 }
```

but when I try:

```
use Mustache\Mustache_Autoloader;

abstract class BaseController {
    public function __construct() {
        Mustache_Autoloader::register();
        /...
   }
   /...
}
```

the error.log said:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mustache\\Mustache_Autoloader' not found in
```

Although, Mustache_Autoloader hasn't namespaces.

Composer has: `composer/autoload_namespaces.php`:

```
 return array(
        'Mustache' => array($vendorDir . '/mustache/mustache/src'),
        //etc 
    );
```

And in my main file I don't forget include `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` But I don't know what happend. Any idea? Thanks.

SOLUTION:

Only I need to add '\' at the beginning of the word. like `new \Mustache_Engine()`.

Now it works. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: try this "mustache/mustache": "2.7.0"

Comment: It doesn't work. 2.7.* it's the current version, and it's the same that 2.7.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, why do you want to use the `Mustache\Mustache_Autoloader` ? 
composer should take care of the autoloading.

Further i see in https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/blob/master/src/Mustache/Autoloader.php
that this class has no namespace.
Therefor `use Mustache\Mustache_Autoloader;` fails.

If you want to use the autoloader you better use:
`require '/path/to/mustache/src/Mustache/Autoloader.php';
Mustache_Autoloader::register();`.

Comment: But in composer/autoload_namespaces.php have:
return array(
    'Mustache' => array($vendorDir . '/mustache/mustache/src'),
    //etc 
);

Comment: yes, so you can simply use ```$m = new Mustache_Engine;``` in your code. composer will autoload the classes. No need for the Mustache/Autoloader, imho.

Comment: But, I need to write in the head of file: `use Mustache\Mustache_Engine;` and I've the same problem...

Comment: Because if I don't write `use` the problem it's `'Controllers\\Mustache_Engine' not found`

Comment: thats weird, ```$m = new Mustache_Engine;``` should be enough according the docs. maybe try ```use Mustache_Engine;```

Comment: Only I need to add '\' at the beginning of the word. like `new \Mustache_Engine()`. Now it works. Thanks a lot!